# How to trigger AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have the following static class that handles some mapping:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration;

    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<User, RegisterViewModel>().ForMember(d => d.Email, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.UserName));
            cfg.CreateMap<User, RegisterViewModel>().ForMember(d => d.Password, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.PasswordHash));
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var user = new User();
        var dest = mapper.Map<User, RegisterViewModel>(user);
    }
}
```

In my Globalasx I Invoke the class like this:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
    AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
 }
```

Now, I have this line in my HomeController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(homeIndexViewModel model)
{

    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(model.Register, model.Register.Password);
}
```

I get the following error here:

> Argument 1: Cannot convert from RegisterViewModel to User

But I have already done the mapping? How can I fix so the mapping that I have defined works through my application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly map the result of your function using the static `Mapper.Map()` method.

See for instance the example on this page: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening

Comment: What's the point of using automapper if you have to do this manually everytime?

Comment: And Im doing the mapping explicitly in my RegisterMappings-method?